# Why results depend on the having clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I can´t understand why the results in the table `clients` which is empty are the following:

```
SELECT SUM(clients.age), COUNT(*)
FROM clients
```

returns

`null`, `0`

But when I add the clause

```
GROUP BY clients.age
```

It returns empty

I can't understand the way in which `GROUP BY` affects the result, because I understand that `GROUP BY` executes before the `SELECT`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your code I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Nothing at all... I just want to understand the behaviour of the RDBMS

Comment: There is generally no reason to `GROUP BY` something and _not_ have it in the SELECT. For example, in the select, change `SUM(clients.age)` to `clients.age` and the result may become clearer. Don't make assumptions about what order things are done in. The query planner decides this. In one situation a join might happen first. In another situation a where might happen before a join. All you can say is that `SELECT` is always last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query with `GROUP BY` requests a result set containing one row for each distinct `clients.age`. Since there aren't any `clients.age` values, 0 rows are returned. Without `GROUP BY` the query requests one row containing aggregates for the whole table. Since a single summary row is requested, it is returned regardless of the fact that the table is empty.